# Read Error When Accessing Local Server with wget

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu

I have a node app running on port 5000 (from a docker container), but I am unable to access it.

I tried running `wget http://localhost:5000` after shelling into the server but I get the following error:

````
--2021-09-09 18:44:44--  http://localhost:5000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2021-09-09 18:45:17--  (try: 2)  http://localhost:5000/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.```

When I run the container on my local computer, I have no trouble accessing it this way, so I'm guessing it's something on the server, but I don't know where to look next.


EDITS

Output of `sudo netstat -anp --tcp | grep 5000 | grep LISTEN`


tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16480/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      16486/docker-proxy
````

Comment: there might be several issues to be pointed at. provide us with more details. It might be of your `port mapping` **[ --port 3000:3000 ]** to be working properly.

Comment: Checked and the port is correctly exposed, added updates on the output of netstat

Comment: It sometimes occurs when your server is located on `127.0.0.1`  or  `localhost`. change it into `0.0.0.0`. or *at least, remove the default server location*. What're more, you can manipulate `IPv6` as well. **disable the IPv6 in your OS** .let me know if it works properly.show me your server file and `Dockerfile` | `docker-compose.yaml` as well if ipossible.

Answer (score 0):

On the server, check that something is listening on port 5000

```
netstat -anp --tcp | grep 5000 | grep LISTEN
```

It should tell you that something is listening to `127.0.0.1:5000` or `0.0.0.0:5000`. The former is a loopback address (only accessible inside the server) and the latter is ANY interface on the server that has an IP (so its accessible outside the server if the local firewall allows it).

If nothing is listening on 5000, then likely the docker container is not exposing the ports.

- You can put `EXPOSE 5000` in your Dockerfile.
- You can add `--expose 5000` to your `docker run` command
- You can add `-p 5000:5000` to your `docker run` command

If you can access port 5000 when you run it on your local computer, it might be working because you have added an environment variable to auto-expose the port.

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16480/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      16486/docker-proxy

Looks like it's exposed as expected.
I'm using a docker-compose file and the appropriate ports are exposed

Comment: @SamAko, a couple of extra things to check:- 1) are you sure the node app listens on port 5000? 2) Is there a proxy configured (make sure `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` are not set). If the node app listens on port 5000 and the port is exposed then you should be able to `telnet localhost 5000` and get connected. Once connected, you can issue `GET / HTTP/1.0` and get some kind of HTTP response. If there is a proxy set, it will not be able to access localhost... but it probably can access the IP of the server if the firewall doesn't prevent it. You can check the firewall rules with `iptables -L`